# Java JPA filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I need to do some checks before execute @Modifying queries like update, insert, delete.
There is any way to do it at Repository level? (Maybe with an annotation). 
What I'm looking for is a filter that has to be executed every time a query is performed and decide if the query has to be executed or not for all my repository files.

Thank you

Comment: for security purposes?

Comment: not only for security...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AspectJ to intercept method calls on JPA repositories.

**Step 1**: Declare your JPA repositories as usual.

**Step 2**: Optionally annotate repository methods of interest.

**Step 3**: Declare an aspect to intercept method calls of interest on JPA repositories.  See [this Aspect](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-jpa-aop/blob/master/src/main/java/org/example/aop/InterceptionAdvice.java) from my sample application as an example.

**Step 4**: Enable runtime interception in the Spring configuration.  See [the XML Spring configuration file](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-jpa-aop/blob/master/src/main/resources/springContext.xml) from the same sample application as an example.

Comment: Yep, correct and remember to throw an exception when you want to prevent the execution of the filtered a method...

Answer (score 0):

This is the snippet of code to check if the @Modifying annotation is present and interrupt the execution with an Exception:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class InterceptModify {

    @Before("execution(* org.example.repository.*.*(..))")
    public void intercept(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
        Annotation[] annotations = signature.getMethod().getAnnotations();

        for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
            if (annotation.annotationType().equals(Modifying.class)) {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
        }
    }}
```

also remeber to enable aspectJ with the annotation @EnableAspectJAutoProxy in one of your conf class